# Multiple User Registration Form vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a user registration form for multiple users. This works fine except the code is unable to identify if there is already username exist. I know there is mistake in my code but I am unable to rectify that one.

Code is below can anyone help me sort this, how to write modify code for reader

```
Private Sub OK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
Dim user, pass As String
user = UsernameTextBox.Text
pass = PasswordTextBox.Text
Dim connection1 As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;      Data Source=Credentials.mdb;")

Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [ID] FROM [Staff] WHERE [usernameField] = username AND [passwordField] = password", connection1)

Dim usernameParam As New OleDbParameter("username", Me.UsernameTextBox.Text)
Dim passwordParam As New OleDbParameter("password",   Me.PasswordTextBox.Text)

command.Parameters.Add(usernameParam)
command.Parameters.Add(passwordParam)

command.Connection.Open()
Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
If reader.HasRows Then
MessageBox.Show("User Exist")
MyPlayer.SoundLocation = path & LogOnsound
PasswordTextBox.Text = ""
UsernameTextBox.Text = ""
ElseIf user = "" Or pass = "" Then
MsgBox("Please Fill The Boxs", , "Error")
Else
Dim connection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Credentials.mdb;"
Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(connection)
myconnection.Open()

Dim sqlq As String = "INSERT INTO [staff] ([username], [password]) VALUES (@user, @pass)"
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlq, myconnection)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usernme", user)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwrd", pass)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("User Registered!", , "register")
user = ""
pass = ""
End Using
End Using
End If
command.Connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple things wrong:

1. You should be specifying `@username` instead of just `username` in your `SELECT` statement so that it will be recognized as a parameter.
2. Why are you checking for a match on `password` also? If you do that, people can have the same username with just a different password...do you want that?
3. In your `SELECT`, you have `usernameField` as the column name in your Staff table, but in your `INSERT`, you have `username` as the column name. Which is it?
4. In your `INSERT`, you specify the parameter `@user`, but in your `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` statement, you have `@usernme`.